# Assembly MIPS: Print a number that have been entered

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm a newbie at assembly and I'm having quite some difficulties with it.

I'm using MARS 4.5 and I want to try to write a code which can take an integer from the keyboard and print it right afterwards.

```
.data  
number: .word 

.text
.globl main 
main: 

li       $v0, 5   
syscall

move     $v0, $a0

li       $v0, 1
la   $a0, ($v0)
syscall


li       $v0, 10       
syscall
```

but when I run this, it returns the value 1 no matter what the input is.

The problem seem to be at the "la    $a0, ($v0)" command.

I though that if I loaded the address of the $v0 register that holds the input number to the standard register for printing integers, it could work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Registers don't have addresses, and the print integer function requires the value not the address anyway. So just delete that line and it should work.

Comment: By deleting the load address command, it returns 0

Comment: You also got the `move` operands reversed.

Comment: You are right. Would it be easier if I stored the input number inside the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  As @Jester explained, you need to remove the load address command and correct your `move` operands.

```
.data  
number: .word 

.text
.globl main 
main: 

li       $v0, 5     #Read integer to $v0
syscall

move     $a0, $v0   #Move integer to $a0

li       $v0, 1     #Print integer from $a0
syscall

li       $v0, 10    #Exit     
syscall
```